# How to create temporal sequence column C so that in each level of column A, a specific message from column B corresponds to 0 in column C

Tags: r

My data contains columns `trial`,`sequence` and `message`, the message `Onset` occurs only once in each trial, but at different `sequence` positions in different `trials`.

```
data<-data.frame(trial=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),sequence=c(1:10,1:10,1:10),message=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"Onset",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"Onset",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"Onset",NA,NA,NA))
```

I want to create a new column called `sequence_new` so that in each `trial` level, the message `Onset` corresponds to "0" in the new column, like the following:

```
data_n<-data.frame(trial=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),sequence=c(1:10,1:10,1:10),message=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,'Onset',NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,'Onset',NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,'Onset',NA,NA,NA),sequence_new=c(-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, sequence_new:=(1:.N)-which(message=='Onset'),trial]
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
     group_by(trial) %>% 
     mutate(sequence_new = row_number()- which(message=='Onset'))
```

Or using `base R`

```
data$sequence_new <-  with(data, ave(seq_along(message), trial, 
              FUN=seq_along) -ave(message=='Onset', trial, FUN=which))
```